# Remove plank without removing elementary-tweaks in Loki?

Tags: system

As title says, i wonder it there are any way to remove plank without elementary-tweaks too, since i installed docky because it supports the magnifying effect that plank does not have.

These 2 packages seems to be linked. Any hints?

Answer (score 1):

They are linked indeed: the package `elementary-tweaks` depends on `plank`, so cannot remove the latter without the former.

However, the fact that plank is installed do not force you to use it, just delete your dock and use docky if you prefer it.